# Using HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync to call my API, how do properly accept the complex type in the API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using `HttpClient` to call my API. I am building up an object and passing it in to the `PostAsJsonAsync` like this:

```
var foo = new Foo 
{
    //We will say these are the only two properties on the model:
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Test"
};

var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("myApiPath/mytest", foo);
```

Then in my API I am trying to grab the `foo` object and do some stuff with it and return a `HttpStatusCode` like this:

```
    [Route("mytest")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage MyTest<T>(T foo)
    {
        //Do some stuff, and return the status code
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

But this doesn't work, I get a `500` error when I use `<T>`.

Just to make sure that I was able to get ahold of the api and pass something in I changed `foo` to `"someRandomString"` and then in the API I changed `MyTest` to just accept a string in like this: `public HttpResponseMessage MyTest(string someRandomString) { }` and that worked fine.

How can I get the complex type to get passed into the API properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller action should not be generic:

```
[Route("mytest")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage MyTest(Foo foo)
{
    //Do some stuff, and return the status code
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

where of course the `Foo` class matches the same properties that you have on the client. To avoid code duplication you could declare your contracts in a separate project that will be shared between your web and client applications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Right before your reply I had just referenced the same models `dll` and was going to try passing around the same model. Glad to know I was on the right path.